# vertical align for text fields

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

how can I align (vertically) some text input fields with CSS?
eg in the following:

```
<form action='<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'>
            <p><label for='username' class=''>Username:</label>
            <input type='text' name='username' id='username' class='field' value='' tabindex='10' /></p>
            <p><label for='password' class=''>Password:</label>
            <input type='text' name='password' id='password' class='field' value='' tabindex='20' /></p>
            <p><label for='e-mail' class=''>E-mail:</label>
            <input type='text' name='e-mail' id='e-mail' class='field' value='' tabindex='35' /></p>
            <p><input type='submit' name='insert' id='insert' class='button' value='Insert!' tabindex='40' /></p>
    </form>
```

Is there anything I can do, aside from using tables?

thanks
Patrick

Comment: I don't understand, what do you want to align vertically and in relation to what?

Comment: The result of your code looks pretty vertical to me... Are you sure you don't mean horizontal? If so, you should use `float: left; width: 200px;` on the `<label>`s.

Comment: just curious: I know that tables aren't good for screen readers (etc...), but would this be such a bad situation to use one? It seems like by far the simplest option with the least amount of code. Don't screen readers read one row at a time, left to right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you want the text boxes aligned with each other like the following. Tip: use the Internet Explorer Developer Tools, Firefox's FireBug or Opera's Dragonfly to tweak the styling attributes in you page.

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<div style='clear:both'>
    <label style='float:left;width:5em;display:block' for='username' class=''>Username:</label>
    <input style='float:left;display:block' type='text' name='username' id='username' class='field' value='' tabindex='10' />
<div>
<div style='clear:both'>
    <label style='float:left;width:5em;display:block' for='password' class=''>Password:</label>
    <input style='float:left;display:block' type='text' name='password' id='password' class='field' value='' tabindex='20' />
</div>
<div style='clear:both'>
    <label style='float:left;width:5em;display:block' for='e-mail' class=''>E-mail:</label>
    <input style='float:left;display:block' type='text' name='e-mail' id='e-mail' class='field' value='' tabindex='35' />
</div>
<div style='clear:both'>
    <input style='width:5em;display:block' type='submit' name='insert' id='insert' class='button' value='Insert!' tabindex='40' />
</div>
```